# How to send jobs on several nodes?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, slurm

I have a R code that I would like to execute on several nodes (SLURM). This is the code :

```
...
res<-foreach(i = seq_len(nrow(combs))) %dopar% {
 G1 <- split[[combs[i,1]]]
 G2 <- split[[combs[i,2]]]
 bind <- cbind(data[,G1], data[,G2])
 rho.i <- cor_rho(bind)     #the function cor_rho I created  
 }
...
```

Actually, it is a comparison of several submatrices where I compute the correlation between each of them, with my function cor_rho.
I want to execute each comparison on a node of the cluster.

Any help?

Bests

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your R script from a bash script, which you will then submit to SLURM requesting a certain number of cores.

If your R code is within a `r_analysis.R` file, you can create a `submit_job.sh` file like that:

```
#! /bin/bash

Rscript r_analysis.R
```

Finally, you submit your job (e.g. from command line) requesting a certain number of CPUs (8 in this example) and memory/CPU (4G in this example):

```
sbatch --mem-per-cpu=4G --cpus-per-task=8 ./submit_job.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. For example, if there are 10 comparisons to compute, could it be possible to create 10 separate jobs where each one executes itself on a node?

Comment: You don't need 10 separate jobs, you submit just one job that specifies the number of cores your task would like to use. I can see your code needs to be ran `nrow(combs)` times (let's say this is equal to 10), so you just need to submit it as:
`sbatch --mem-per-cpu=4G --cpus-per-task=10 ./submit_job.sh` and change memory requirements to larger than 4G values if each iteration uses a lot of memory. Please also upvote if you find any of it useful..

Comment: I explain why I would like to use X nodes. The matrix I use has 817.000 columns and I need to compute the correlation between these 817.000 columns (which is impossible on only one node) . I know that with one node of my cluster (256Go, 32CPUs), I can compute 60.000 columns. Then, I have divided this matrix into 817k/60k ~ 14 submatrices . There will be (14*13)/2 =  91 combinations to compute. That's why I would like to execute each computation on a node ..

Comment: You can specify explicitly the number of nodes with the `--nodes` option when running `sbatch`.
Have you tried submitting and getting an error message like `configuration not available'?

Comment: But it will imply that if I put `--nodes 91` , each computation of the combinations will go on one of these 91 nodes?